# Detox build command saving to `Release-iphonesimulator` rather than `Debug-iphonesimulator`; tests failing to find the app binary

Tags: ios, react-native, jestjs, ios-simulator, detox

I have a RN project (not in expo) and I'm trying to add detox. In my `.detoxrc.json` I have configured the `binaryPath` to be `"./ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app-name>.app"`, but the actual output of `yarn detox build -c ios` always goes to `"./ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/<app-name>.app"` (note the `Release-iphonesimulator`). So when I try to run tests, I get the following error:

```bash
10:10:18.446 detox[5677] ERROR: Failed to find the app binary at:
/Users/<me>/Documents/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app-name>.app
```

How can I ensure that on `build` the output goes to the correct filepath?

for reference, here's my full `.detoxrc.json`:

```json
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
  "apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "./ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app-name>.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<app-name>.xcworkspace -configuration debug -scheme '<app-name>' -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/feat/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleFeatDebug -x bundleFeatReleaseJsAndAssets -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 13 Pro"
      }
    },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_32_arm64-v8a"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was a typo in the `"build"` instruction. Should be `Debug`, with a capital D.